# Simple Refinement Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, domain-model, refinement-type

From Scott Wlaschin's [blog post](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-more-semantic-types/) and Book "Domain Modeling made Functional", and from Alexis King's [post](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/), I take that a domain model should encode as much information about the domain as is practical in the types, so as to "make illegal states unrepresentable" and to obtain strong guarantees that allows me to write domain logic functions that are total.

In basic enterprise applications, we have many basic domain types like street names, company names, cities and the like. To represent them in a form that prevents most errors later on, I would like to use a type that lets me

- restrict the maximum and minimum number of characters.
- specify the subset of characters that may be used,
- add additional constraints, like no leading or trailing whitespace.

I can think of two ways to implement such types: As custom abstract data types with smart constructors and hidden data constructors, or via some type-level machinery (I vaguely read about refinement types? Can such types be represented via some of the newer language extensions? via LiquidHaskell?). Which is the sensible way to go? Which approach most easily works with all the functions that operate on regular `Text`, and how can I most easily combine two or more values of the same refined type, map over them, etc.?

Ideally, there would be a library to help me create such custom types. Is there?

Comment: Consider Liquid Haskell, which strikes a nice balance between your two options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following Alexis King's blog, I'd say that a suitable solution would be something like below. Of course, other solutions are posible.

```
import Control.Monad (>=>)

newtype StreetName = StreetName {getStreetName :: String}

-- compose all validations and wrap them in new constructor.
asStreetName :: String -> Maybe StreetName
asStreetName = StreetName <$> rightNumberOfChars >=> rightCharSubset >=> noTrailingWhiteSpace

-- This funcs will process the string, and produce another validated string or nothing. 
rightNumberOfChars :: String -> Maybe String
rightNumberOfChars s = {- ... -}

rightCharSubset :: String -> Maybe String
rightCharSubset s = {- ... -}

noTrailingWhiteSpace :: String -> Maybe String
noTrailingWhiteSpaces = {- ... -}

main = do
  street <- readStreetAsString
  case asStreetName street of
    Just s  -> {- s is now validated -}
    Nothing -> {- handle the error -}
```

make `StreetName` a hiden constructor, as use `asStreetName` as a smart constructor. Remember that other functions should use `StreetName` instead of `String` in the type, to make sure that data is validated.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I've been thinking along these lines for a while. But I am surprised that this pattern does not seem to be used widely in Haskell applications, and that there are not that many libraries to simplify defining such types. Is it "too simple" for the typical Haskeller?

Comment: When trying out this solution, I added pattern Synonyms so that I can pattern-match on the value without exposing the data constructor.

Comment: @UlrichSchuster The usage of pattern Synonyms as smart constructors is a great idea actually! probably under-used within haskell ecosystem. I wonder why... I don't think it is "too simple", probably just not so promoted as other extensions...